# Round up double to long in Java

Tags: java, double, long-integer, rounding

Is there a method in java which round up double to Long in java?

eg.
double d=2394867326.23;
I need to round this up to 2394867327. The result is not an integer, so I think cannot use Math.ceil.

Do we have a method in java which return the Long instead of int?

Comment: You should actually look at the documentation for `Math.ceil()`...

Comment: yep, `Math.ceil()` is the one.

Comment: What should happen if your double exceeds the long range?

Answer (score 8):

Math.ceil returns a double according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29), so you should just be able to cast it to a long after calling math.ceil(double).

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on the property that a cast to long will always truncate:

```
public static long d2lCeil(double d) {
    long l = (long) d;
    return d == l ? l : l + 1;
}
```

The trick this method is using is that in the cast to long any fraction will be simply lost. The presence of a fraction is then detected by comparing the long and double, if they're not the same there must be a fraction, thus the long needs to be rounded up.